# Application is taking time to load in ionic2

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, ionic2

We need guidance for our one of requirements in ionic2. We want to create an application with ionic2 which can run on Mobile (in iOS & Android as hybrid application) as well as on Desktop and Mobile browsers.

We have created a sample application as mentioned in the ionic2 tutorials.
After building the app, we found:

- The app is taking time to load the first page, because an app is being bundled in a single .js file (app.bundle.js) with size of approximately 2.8 MB (because of Webpack functionality).
- After minification, it's reduced down to approx. 1.2 MB.
- Right now this is just a sample application with default menu option coming by default from github.
- Our concern is after adding the project code, it will definitely increase in size and hence would take time to load the app.
- So we want to use Lazy loading concept of file loading.
- We want to load the files which are related to current modules only, instead of loading tje bundled .js file at the time of launching the application, so the app can load faster.

Please provide help on the below points:

1. Can we use ionic2 for desktop browser along with mobile hybrid app (and use a single codebase for a hybrid mobile app for desktop browsers too)?
2. If the answer is yes for point 1, then please suggest the correct way of doing this.
3. What can we do to reduce the load time of the application?
4. How can we configure the application to reduce down the size of app.bundle.js?
5. How can we use lazy loading (load related .js files on demand)?

Answer (score 0):

It is really an issue with ionic2 app.

I have also seen this issue, for my case it used to take about 10 to 12 Second to get app launched.
After seeing some articles i came to optomixed it up to 8 second.
each time there is cache get store which we need to remove by using this lines,

I got some good ideas and suggested the following meta data at top of index.html (for web deployment).

```
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Hope that help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try building your app with the "--pro --release" flags like "ionic build ios --pro --release" because this will start Ahead of Time (AoT) compilation and make your app launch way faster!